# Excel Message box when cell value more than 100

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that have 2 rows, the first one is " Item " and the second is " Weight ".

the " Weight " will calculated and if the total summary is more than 100 % then Excel will show Warning Box.

[image: The form]

Can you guys help me to find a way to make it in Excel?

this is script I use before:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Me.Range("A2:B10")
    If Target.Value > 100 Then
        MsgBox "You exceeded 100"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say form, are you talking about an Excel UserForm? The image you show appears to be from a sheet but the row numbers and column letters are not included. Because the total is in a merged cell, the value will belong to the cell in the upper left corner cell of the merged cells. What is that Cell Address of the upper left corner of the merged total group?

Answer (score 1):

> the " Weight " will calculated

so you can do 1 of two things, 1) base the worksheet_change event on the cell that will be changed to affect the calculation and check the result of the calculation:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2:B10") is nothing Then
        If Me.Range("A2").Value > 100 Then 
            MsgBox "You exceeded 100"
       End If
    End If

End Sub
```

or 2) you can use the Calculate Event, this will fire each time the sheet calculates:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If Range("A2").Value > 100 Then 
        MsgBox "You exceeded 100"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you may need both. Calculate for subtotals and change for user input.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you had in mind?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2:B10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            If .Value > 100 Then
                MsgBox "You exceeded 100"
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code will only run if one of the cells in the Range(A2:B10) was changed. It will look at the changed cell (that is *Target*) and issue a message if its value is greater than 100.

Referring to your comment, the variation of the above code given below would draw a total of the cells in the monitored range, issue a message if that total exceeds 1 and return the selection to the faulty cell. Note that percentages are expressed divided by 100. Therefore the value 1 would be displayed as 100%.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const RangeAddress As String = "A2:B10"
    Dim Ttl As Double

    With Target
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range(RangeAddress), Target) Is Nothing Then
            Ttl = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RangeAddress)
            If Ttl > 1 Then
                MsgBox "You exceeded 100%"
                .Select
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, what if i want to make the form like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/plBwT.png

Comment: If the change is to multiple cells and any of them overlap with A2:B10, this will cause a runtime error.

Comment: @Ted D Changing multiple cells is only possible by using Paste.

Comment: or selecting multiple cells and then hit delete or selecting and dragging a selection across multiple rows or down multiple columns (select A1:A2 drag selection to C1:C2 - target will be B1:C2) and maybe some I haven't thought of.

Comment: @Ted D. Yes, if a professional solution is required that should indeed be taken into consideration.

Comment: @Jojo Forum rules require that additional information should be made by modifying the question itself, not by adding to comments. My own rules suggest that I shouldn't allow shifting of goal posts. However, I have made an exception and added to my answer. I hope the Forum will also forgive you since this is your first experience here :-)

Comment: One more thing: It takes a lot of experience to correctly deal with merged cells in a worksheet. That's why experienced programmers avoid them.

Comment: @Variatus Note that your first code block fails if `Target` is a range and not a single cell (which happens easily when you copy-paste). In this case `Target.Value` returns an array that cannot be validated against `> 100` in a single `If` statement. Therefore you need to loop through all cells in `Set IntersectetdRange = Application.Intersect(Range("A2:B10"), Target)` eg `For Each Cel in IntersectetdRange)` and then check `If Cel.Value > 100 Then`. • When using `Worksheet_Change` always keep in mind that `Target` can be a multi-cell range.

Comment: @PEH Avoid applying a yardstick to my answer that you don't normally apply to your own. The object here isn't to provide indestructible code of high professional standard but to put the OP on a path toward finding his own way. If you consider your comments significant in that sense please address them to the OP. They are definitely well taken but may not be relevant.

Comment: @Variatus Sorry if my comment came wrong, I didn't meant to be pedantic "just because". But any range copy/paste action in this sheet that affects the range `A2:B10` will *definitly* break the code and come up with an unhandled exception in the VBE. Actually copy/paste is a fairly often used command on sheets and not something extraordinary I constructed in my mind to break your code (if you saw my comment like this). • I just posted this comment because I see a fairly *high* chance to break it in a common daily use of a sheet. I mean copy/paste of a range is nothing unexpected or spactacular.